# I want two way binding in the my dropdown menu

Tags: angular, typescript, two-way-binding

I want use two way binding in my Component . but it's not working. I don't understand why?

About the details:

DropdownComponent click event is change the variable selected. but i want synchronize change AppComponent the variable select.

it's my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmcy7h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

I expect just like this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-twoway-bindings-simple?embed=1&file=app/custom-counter.component.ts)

Comment: What is not working? Which part? And what or how do you expect them to work? [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I see that you have demo code that's good. But it's unclear what do you expect from the example.

Comment: I expect select menu item sync change DropdownComponent.selected and AppComponent.select two variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [two way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---) on a property foo you need a companion property named fooChanged

> The [(x)] syntax is easy to demonstrate when the element has a settable property called x and a corresponding event named xChange. Here's a SizerComponent that fits the pattern. It has a size value property and a companion sizeChange event

So if we take your example you need to simplify your dropdown component code to:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.css']
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  isOpen = false;
  @Input() selected ;
  @Input() data;
  @Output() selectedChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  selectItem(item) {
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.selected = item;
    this.selectedChange.emit(this.selected);
  }


}
```

and use it like this:

```
<app-dropdown [(selected)]="select" [data]="['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']"></app-dropdown>
```

Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkxedg

Answer (score 0):

`my-app` component needs to start listening to `itemChange` EventEmiiter.

Change `app.component.html` template to

```html
<h1 >AppComponent selected: {{ select }}</h1>
<p>
    <app-dropdown (itemChange)="select=$event" [data]="['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']"></app-dropdown>
</p>
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you answer! but i want  two way binding to do working.

Answer (score 0):

Change your app component like this

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  select = 'i want change select';

  onSelect(text: string) {
    this.select = text;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1 >AppComponent selected: {{ select }}</h1>
<p>
  <app-dropdown (itemChange)="onSelect($event)" [data]="['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']"></app-dropdown>
</p>
```